# Clone a branch from subversion to mercurial with complete history (even past the branch to parents)

Tags: svn, mercurial

Is there a way to create a mercurial repository with the complete history of a subversion branch?  All the methods I have seen effectively do a stop on copy, stopping the history when the branch was created.  Is there a way to pull the entire history, back through previous branches, and even down to the trunk?

Comment: Have you tried converting all the repository, then stripping the unnecessary branches?

Answer (score -1):

use the `convert` extension

```
$ hg convert --authors <file> <svn repo> <new-hg-repo>
```

where `<file>` is your authors file to map svn short names to long names and emailID containing for instance:

```
vbajpai = Vaibhav Bajpai <contact@vaibhavbajpai.com>
```

This also fallbacks to svn shortnames if no mapping is found.

`convert` automatically makes `trunk`, `tags` and `branches` as separate branches in your `new-hg-repo`.

To enable `convert` extension, add this to your `.hgrc`

```
[extensions]
convert =
```

Comment: That doesn't address the question asked, I don't want the whole repository, I want the entire history of *1* branch, going back past the creation of the branch to the beginning of time.